# COUNT DISTINCT not adding up

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to count the amount of unique `CNTR_NBR` for the day

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(BEGIN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') "DATE"
        , TRAN_TYPE_DESC
        , MENU_OPTN_NAME
        , REASON_CODE
        , REF_FIELD_3  "RC_REF_1"
        , COUNT (DISTINCT CNTR_NBR) AS LPNS
FROM WMS2018.BAP_PROD_TRKG_TRAN_VIEW
WHERE MENU_OPTN_NAME = 'Receive and Sort DCV'
      AND TRUNC(BEGIN_DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY BEGIN_DATE
        , TRAN_TYPE_DESC
        , MENU_OPTN_NAME
        , REASON_CODE
        , REF_FIELD_3
    ORDER BY 1
    ;
```

this is what its currently returning

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds. It **ALWAYS** has those components.

Some user interfaces chose to have a default where they do not show the time component of `DATE`s and SQL Developer happens to be like that. You can change the date format in the preferences or using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

and then you will see the full date and time in each group.

When you `GROUP BY begin_date` you are asking it to group down to a precision of one second (not a day); you need to change it so that the groups span an entire day.

You can use `TO_CHAR` or `TRUNC` in the `GROUP BY` clause to group by the day:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(BEGIN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') "DATE"
        , TRAN_TYPE_DESC
        , MENU_OPTN_NAME
        , REASON_CODE
        , REF_FIELD_3  "RC_REF_1"
        , COUNT (DISTINCT CNTR_NBR) AS LPNS
FROM   WMS2018.BAP_PROD_TRKG_TRAN_VIEW
WHERE  MENU_OPTN_NAME = 'Receive and Sort DCV'
AND    BEGIN_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    BEGIN_DATE <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(BEGIN_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
        , TRAN_TYPE_DESC
        , MENU_OPTN_NAME
        , REASON_CODE
        , REF_FIELD_3
ORDER BY 1;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(BEGIN_DATE), 'DD-MM-YYYY') "DATE"
        , TRAN_TYPE_DESC
        , MENU_OPTN_NAME
        , REASON_CODE
        , REF_FIELD_3  "RC_REF_1"
        , COUNT (DISTINCT CNTR_NBR) AS LPNS
FROM   WMS2018.BAP_PROD_TRKG_TRAN_VIEW
WHERE  MENU_OPTN_NAME = 'Receive and Sort DCV'
AND    BEGIN_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    BEGIN_DATE <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
GROUP BY TRUNC(BEGIN_DATE)
        , TRAN_TYPE_DESC
        , MENU_OPTN_NAME
        , REASON_CODE
        , REF_FIELD_3
ORDER BY TRUNC(BEGIN_DATE);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, i tried both your suggestions and it did group some of them but still not all.

Comment: @MarkP, Can you please create a fiddle with you r sample data?

Comment: @MarkP You include `REF_FIELD_3` in the `GROUP BY` clause; each of the rows in your output has a different value for that field so they will be in a different group. What else were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Hi @MT0 yes i realized this shortly after. its all good now.
Also how do i add in the query like you did?
 thanks everyone